# Get relational data with MySQL join?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I've been unable to find a good reference on how to use joins to accomplish a certain goal in MySQL.

I have a pages table, a categories table, and a pagecategories table. The rough structure of each:

pages: 'id', 'name', 'content'
categories: 'id', 'name'
pagecategories: 'pageid', 'categoryid'

I want to be able to use a query to get the category of a page, as well as the pages in a certain category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.name, a.content,
        b.name as CategoryName
FROM    pages a
        INNER JOIN pagecategories b
            ON a.ID = b.pageID
        INNER JOIN categories c
            ON b.categoryID = c.ID
-- WHERE a.ID = IDHERE       -- <<== if you want to filter for a specific page
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)